# Remove controlBox, minimizeBox, and maximizeBox in full screen

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to create an interface that has MDI child forms that open in full screen mode within the parent and the controlBox, minimizeBox, and maximizeBox all show up in full screen even though I have them all set to false. Anyone know how to fix this?
[image]

Here is the code I am using to switch between screens (children forms) they should open in full screen mode because the default I set them with, but I need to get rid of the minimize, maximize, and control buttons.

```
public partial class Parent : Form
{
    Form activeForm = new Form2();
    public Parent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Parent_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        activeForm.MdiParent = this;
        activeForm.Show();
    }

    private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(toolStripTextBox1.Text == "1")
        {
            activeForm.Close();
            activeForm = new Form2();
            activeForm.MdiParent = this;
            activeForm.Show();
        }
        if (toolStripTextBox1.Text == "2")
        {
            activeForm.Close();
            activeForm = new Form3();
            activeForm.MdiParent = this;
            activeForm.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: MDI forms will fight you if you use any border other than the Resize.  MDI is probably considered a deprecated technique at this point. Consider dumping it and use UserControls instead of Forms and dock fill inside a panel.  Your screen shot certainly doesn't look like it needs to be an MDI application.

Comment: @LarsTech I just spent the last 40 minutes trying to figure out how to do that. I created the UserControls but I cannot find out how to programmatically add and remove/show and hide them. Any thoughts? Thanks for the help!

Comment: `yourPanel.Controls.Add(new yourControl() { Dock = Fill });`  Make sure you dispose of any controls in the panel beforehand.  Calling `Controls.Clear()` does not dispose the control.

Comment: @LarsTech Thank you so much! I was trying to add the controls to the form instead of the panel; your example fixed that for me!

Answer (score 0):

set the controlbox to false, for any form which you prefer not to have minimizeBox, MaximizeBox and Close.

```
  activeForm.ControlBox = false;
```